# Is there a way to programmatically set the webhook URL for inbound SMS on MessageBird?

Tags: node.js, webhooks, messagebird

I would like to **programmatically** set the webhook URL for incoming SMS on **MessageBird** instead of using the **Flow Builder** manually.
Thanks

Edit: it's for incoming SMS, not conversations.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't!**
You have to use the **Flow Builder**!